# How to catch raiserror from tigger in yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

I'm use yii2 to catch raiserror in my sqlserver

This my controller :

```
try{
    $model->save();
}catch(Exception $e){
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

But the result is allways **General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [3903] (severity 16) [(null)]**

This my sql code in my trigger :

```
BEGIN
    if exists ( select 1
                from db_name b 
                join db_name2 c on b.ma_id=c.ma_id
                where (ma_ppwq is null or rtrim(ma_ppwq)='' or ma_ppwq='0' or ma_ppwq_name is null or rtrim(ma_ppwq_name) ='' or ma_ppwq_name='0' or ma_ppwq_address is null or rtrim(ma_ppwq_address) ='' or ma_ppwq_address='0')
                and c.ma_id=@ma_id)

    begin 
    rollback                                 
raiserror ('Data Incomplete',16,-1)
    end
END
```

Why the result not print 'Data incomplete' ?

Thanks